# Redirect only with specific domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a website with 2 different domains, for example:

**www.example.com
www.example.net**

Now i want, that every user coming from **example.com** should be redirected to **www.example.de**

Ill tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://example.de/$0 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

But now still all users from **example.net** get redirected to **example.de**

How can i solve that, that only users from **example.com** gets redirected (also with all subfolders).

Thanks!

Comment: Remove `!` from `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this - you want to match example.com (remove the !), and it's clearer to capture the incoming url into $1.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.de/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

Also, while debugging, change the `R=301` to `R`, so your browser doesn't "stick" with an old rule. When it works, change it back to `R=301`

Comment: Thanks - but its still not working. When ill try example.net it is still redirecting - ill checked already if there are others rules, but there is nothing here. Its a simple hosting provider, so i dont know how he handles the multiple domains. Any other ideas?

Comment: Try browser in incognito mode, or clear history/cache. There's a chance the browser cached the original redirect (Chrome does this a lot).

Comment: Oh ok, it seems that the browser already cached the redirect. Ill try it now again with another browser

Comment: Thanks - now tried again with deleting the browser cache. When ill remove the "!" its not working (so there is no redirect) - maybe you have another idea?

Comment: If these rules are on the example.com website, it should definitely be redirecting. (These rules don't do www.example.com, just example.com). As @anubhava said in his comment, removing the ! should have worked (even without my other changes). Does it do anything at all, or does it stay on example.com?

Comment: Ah you are right, its redirecting from example.com well (not with www.) - but still the problem that both urls get redirected :(

Comment: Then it still might be the browser thing - it's hard to get rid of it. Try incognito mode. If that still redirects, it may be something with how the host is set up, so you may have to talk to the provider (e.g,. if they're somehow mapping example.net to example.com, so it's coming through with HTTP_HOST as .com for both - just guessing).

Comment: Ok thanks for your help!  I will ask the provider here. Maybe you can tell me how to get www.example.com and example.com redirected?

Comment: Easiet way is remove the `^` from the front of example.com. There are other posts if you want to make it more specific to www.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82008/discussion-between-goodeye-and-derdida).

Comment: @goodeye your tip about changing R=301 to R is brilliant mate. That has been giving me so much trouble