# Is it possible to mask a URL in either Javascript or PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, url, dns

I have a website hosted with a domain (www.example1.com).

When viewers access this website, I want everything to remain exactly as is however, I want to change the URL in the browser to appear as www.example2.com.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why?  The only reasons that spring to mind are not nice ones.  Also, if you navigate to example1 then the URL will display as example1.  What not-nice people do is then use tricks like an iframe to navigate to example2 without the user noticing.

Comment: I have technical reasons for this. I promise it is nothing malicious. :D

Comment: @cleverpaul and I believe you, fellow denizen of the Internet! Could using subdomains solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

"When viewers access this website, I want everything to remain exactly as is however, I want to change the URL in the browser to appear as www.example2.com."

No, you can't do this with Chrome, Edge, IE, Firefox, etc. because they don't want to let you impersonate apple.com or microsoft.com etc.

You can only do the reverse:  have your example1.com URL be visible while you display content from example2.  This could be done with tricks like an iframe or fetching the content server-side with cURL.

If you want to hide the URL for example1.com you'll need to make your own browser using a chromium widget, the IE web control, webkit.  If it's your own browser you can display anything you want in the address bar or show no address bar at all.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try the following:**

1. You should own both of the domains `example1.com` and `example2.com`.
2. The domain `example2.com` should point to the IP of the server hosting your web app In your name server configuration.
3. The domain `example1.com` should be configured to forward to `example2.com` (also from the name server).

So, visitors to `example1.com` will be redirected to `example2.com` and see the content of the web app while the address bar remains pointing to `example1.com`.

**Another solution:**

1. Both domains should point to the IP of the server hosting your web app.
2. In the web server, you can configure to redirect to `example2.com` only if the request was for `example1.com`.
   Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31145847/redirect-only-with-specific-domain) about doing so in Apache web server.

**Using PHP**

You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459739/php-serverhttp-host-vs-serverserver-name-am-i-understanding-the-ma) about checking the host domain name and then you can redirect if the domain is `example1.com`